# No error on import static Singleton in java

Tags: java

I have followed Singleton:

```
public class GameConfig {

    private static GameConfig mGameConfig = null;

    private String mStr = "Boo";

    public static GameConfig getInstance(){

    if(mGameConfig == null){
        mGameConfig = new GameConfig();
    }

    return mGameConfig;
}

    private GameConfig(){}

    public String getStr() {
      return mStr;
    }
}
```

Now I try to do some experiment:

Lets say I have other class `User` that goes to use this singelton:

```
public class User{

  ....

  private void init(){
    String str = GameConfig.getInstance().getStr();
  }

}
```

So far so good.

I'll take above mentioned class `User` and add `import static`:

```
import static com.app.utils.GameConfig.getInstance; // no error, why?? 

public class User{

  ....

  private void init(){
    String str = GameConfig.getInstance().getStr();

    //  I can't type 
    // String str = getStr(); !!
    // getInstance return instance
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect an error?

Comment: Why, do you *want* an error?

Comment: because static imports let you avoid qualifying static members with class names but `getInstance` is method

Comment: You have to use `getInstance().getStr()` because `getInstance` is the static method you point to with the static import. `getStr` isn't static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is there no error? Because that's valid syntax. Isn't it good for things to work?

```
import static com.app.utils.GameConfig.getInstance; // no error, why??
```

will make `getInstance()` available without naming the class, for instance:

```
GameConfig gc=getInstance();
```

As a side note, I'd rename the method to be more descriptive, like `getGameConfig`.

Comment: As a side note `getInstance()` is used for singletons, it's descriptive.

Comment: @nachokk right but after converting `GameConfig.getInstance()` to `getInstance()`, better to use `getGameConfig`, because you don't see the instance of what

Comment: @nachokk Yes, Maxim is really right. If you have 2 different singletons `getInstance()` confuses and deceives.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language specification has the answer. First, [the definition of a member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)

> A class body may contain declarations of members of the class, that
>   is, fields (§8.3), methods (§8.4), classes (§8.5), and interfaces
>   (§8.5).
>
> A class body may also contain instance initializers (§8.6), static
>   initializers (§8.7), and declarations of constructors (§8.8) for the
>   class.

And the [definition of a single `static` import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3)

> A single-static-import declaration imports all accessible static
>   members with a given simple name from a type. This makes these static
>   members available under their simple name in the class and interface
>   declarations of the compilation unit in which the single-static-import
>   declaration appears.
>
> SingleStaticImportDeclaration:
>
> ```
> import static TypeName . Identifier ;
> ```

The `static` method `getInstance` is a `static` member of the `GameConfig` class. You can therefore import it with

```
import static com.app.utils.GameConfig.getInstance;
```

---

If in the below

```
//  I can't type 
// String str = getStr(); !!
```

you meant for `getStr()` to be `static` method of `GameConfig`, it makes sense that it won't compile, since you haven't imported that member.

Comment: @MaximShoustin The JLS says methods are also members, just like classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error becuase the static import is valid. static imports allow to import the static content from a class. This allows to use the static variables/methods directly wihtout using the class name.

Also you cannot use `getStr` directly because that is not a `static` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a valid static import.So no error.
According to java [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members, either individually.  at

Here `getInstance()` is `static` member so it is valid import statement.